# Migration didn't properly handle Room database (java.lang.IllegalStateException)

Tags: android, android-room

I have Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data. in crash report

Why here every thing is empty in **TableInfo**

Expected:

> TableInfo{name='card_data',
> columns={bPathImg=Column{name='bPathImg', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
> notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> cardName=Column{name='cardName', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
> notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> cardId=Column{name='cardId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'},
> cardType=Column{name='cardType', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
> notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> time=Column{name='time', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false,
> primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> fPathImg=Column{name='fPathImg', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
> notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> sqlDate=Column{name='sqlDate', type='TEXT', affinity='2',
> notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},
> cardNumber=Column{name='cardNumber', type='INTEGER', affinity='3',
> notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}},
> foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

Found:

> TableInfo{name='card_data',
> columns={}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

**Here is my entity class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "card_data")
@Keep
public class CardDataEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int cardId;
    private String cardName;
    private String time;
    private String sqlDate;
    private int cardNumber;
    private String fPathImg;
    private String bPathImg;
    private String cardType;
    @Ignore
    private boolean isHeader;

    public CardDataEntity(String cardName, String time, String sqlDate, int cardNumber, String fPathImg, String bPathImg, String cardType) {

        this.cardName = cardName;
        this.time = time;
        this.sqlDate = sqlDate;
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
        this.fPathImg = fPathImg;
        this.bPathImg = bPathImg;
        this.cardType = cardType;
        this.isHeader = false;

    }

    // setter getter here

}
```

**and here is my database class**

```
@Database(entities = {ScanDataEntity.class , ScanDataBookmarkEntity.class,
        GenerateDataEntity.class, GenerateBookmarkDataEntity.class, CardDataEntity.class, CardBookmarkDataEntity.class},
        version = 7, exportSchema = false)

public abstract class ScanDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract ScanDataDao scanDataDao();
    // DAO classes

    private static ScanDatabase dataBase;

    public static ScanDatabase getInstance(Context context){
        if (null== dataBase){
            dataBase= buildDatabaseInstance(context);
        }
        return dataBase;
    }

    private static final Migration MIGRATION_6_7 = new Migration(6, 7) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            try {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE generate_data "
                        + " ADD COLUMN generateImgPath TEXT");
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
   
    // same migration for other versions 

    private static ScanDatabase buildDatabaseInstance(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                ScanDatabase.class,
                "scan_database")
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_6_7,MIGRATION_5_7,MIGRATION_4_7,MIGRATION_3_7,MIGRATION_2_7,MIGRATION_1_7)
//                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .allowMainThreadQueries().build();

    }

}
```

Can anyone help me please, I really don't know what I'm doing wrong or if it is a bug.

Comment: Did the card_data table previously exist? It appears that it didn't. If it didn't then you need to create the table in MIGRATION_6_7. You can get the SQL for the table by looking at the project in Android View and then looking in the java(generated) in the file ScanDatabase_Impl file. It will be in the createAllTables method.

Comment: yes `card_data` table exits in previously

Comment: Just to be sure and the card_data entity has always been as you have shown? That is it certainly appears that Room is finding a database with a card_table that has none of the columns (which could be no table at all (can't remember if the error for no table is as above or not)).  Personally what I'd do is copy the database and open it in an SQLite tool such as DBBeaver and inspect it's schema.

Answer (score 0):

Specify column names with [@ColumnInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ColumnInfo) annotation to provide column data associated with this field.
Like

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "cardId")
private int cardId;
.....
```

Comment: No need for @ColumnInfo, as can be seen the Expected is as per the Entity. The Found is what Room has found. In this case a database has been accessed who's card_data table has no unhidden columns.

Comment: @MikeT What I can do now?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up here with the same error. For future readers who end up here, too:

In my case I had a simple typo in the self-generated Schema-files:

Schema `8.json`

```
"tableName": "measurement",
        "createSql": "CREATE TABLE measurement...
```

Migration 8 to 12:

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE measurement RENAME TO measurements;")
```

Schema `12.json`:

```
"tableName": "measurement",
        "createSql": "CREATE TABLE measurements ...
```

- The cause for the error was: `tableName` should be `measurmentS` not `measurement`

*Hope this helps others, too, as the error itself did not really help me identifying this typo.*